# Detecting touches on a UIImageView in IPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I'm programming a King Chess game on the iPhone. When the user touches a square on the screen, I want to know which square was selected.

I am using UIImageViews to show squares on the screen.

Comment: in which language are you developing?
MonoTouch (C#) or objective-C? or ??

Comment: Whether every square is a separate UIImageView or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in [touchesEnded:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW1) method , u can get the position of ur touch.
Then , u go thru all the image views (squares) , comparing their frame positions using [CGRectIntersectsRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGRect) and find which square is touched.

Comment: Doesn't sound optimal, but if you need to use UIImageViews, a viable option

Answer (score 1):

UIImageview would not be feasible in your scenario. You can use UIButton with customtype and assign image to that button. So it looks like button but you can add target and you know which square touch/pressed.

Hope this help.